# Getting segmentation fault. Invalid memory write of size 1 on Valgrind (CS50 PSET5 Speller)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

Can't seem to make Valgrind happy.

Valgrind Result:

==21003== Invalid write of size 1
==21003==    at 0x4C32E0D: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21003==    by 0x40125E: load (dictionary.c:111)
==21003==    by 0x400964: main (speller.c:40)

Invalid write of size 8
==22741==    at 0x40123E: load (dictionary.c:107)
==22741==    by 0x400964: main (speller.c:40)
==22741==  Address 0x55cd9a0 is 32 bytes before an unallocated block of size 4,183,584 in arena "client"

Problem seems to be in line 110 which is StrCpy in my bool LOAD.
Code as below - I can't understand why there's an invalid write of size 1.

Another one is 
n -> next = table[hashInt];

I don't understand why I am getting invalid write.

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    char word [LENGTH + 1];

    while (fscanf(file, "%s\n", word) != EOF)
    {

        int hashInt = hash(word);

        node *n = malloc(sizeof(n));

        if (n == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return 1;
        }

        if (table[hashInt] == NULL)
        {
            table[hashInt] = n;
        }
        else
        {
            n -> next = table[hashInt];
            table[hashInt] = n;
        }

        strcpy(n -> word, word);
        wordLoaded++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `node *n = malloc(sizeof(n));` is probably a typo. Did you mean `sizeof(node)`?

Comment: Goodness Gracious, this seems to fix it. Thank you.